# Php code ends with blank screen

Tags: php

I have this PHP code, I am validating and fetch query accordingly.. but though my query is firing but it ends with blank screen. I have commented the location with `die()`;

```
for ($z = 0; $z < count($track); $z++) {
    if ( in_array($track[$z], $already_track)) {
        $at_key = array_search($track[$z], $already_track);
        $a = explode(":", $artist[$z]);
        $b = explode(":", $already_artist[$at_key]);
        $array_compared = array_diff($a, $b);

        if (empty($array_compared)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracklist(aid, sid, rid, added_by, added_on) VALUES('".$album."', '".$track[$z]."', '".$artist[$z]."', '".$_SESSION["userkey"]."', '" . $time . "' )") or die(mysql_error());
            //die("Yes Here"); //My code output blank screen after this query. Though query fired successully.
        }
    } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracklist(aid, sid, rid, added_by, added_on) VALUES('".$album."', '".$track[$z]."', '".$artist[$z]."', '".$_SESSION["userkey"]."', '" . $time . "' )") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: A "blank screen" might suggest that your PHP is configured to output errors to an error log rather than to the browser. What does the error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would set this line at the top of the script to enable all errors:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Then, I would print something on the screen to see if you script goes in the "true" part of the "if" or in the "false" (else).

Finally, I would dump on the screen all the variable you put in your SELECT statement.  Your variables are not escaped so it may be the reason why you have an error.  Outputing the SQL statement and running it directly in MySQL will also tell you if the error comes from that part.

Any quote (single or double) in your data may have an impact on your SQL.

Edited code would be:

```
    for ($z = 0; $z < count($track); $z++)   {
        if ( in_array($track[$z], $already_track)){
            $at_key = array_search($track[$z], $already_track);
            $a = explode(":", $artist[$z]);
            $b = explode(":", $already_artist[$at_key]);
            $array_compared = array_diff($a, $b);
            if(empty($array_compared)){
                continue;
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO tracklist(aid, sid, rid, added_by, added_on) VALUES('".$album."', '".$track[$z]."', '".$artist[$z]."', '".$_SESSION["userkey"]."', '" . $time . "' )";
                echo 'First else.';
                var_dump($track, $artist, $album, $_SESSION["userkey"]);
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                var_dump($res);
           }
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tracklist(aid, sid, rid, added_by, added_on) VALUES('".$album."', '".$track[$z]."', '".$artist[$z]."', '".$_SESSION["userkey"]."', '" . $time . "' )";
            echo 'Second else.';
            var_dump($track, $artist, $album, $_SESSION["userkey"]);
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
            var_dump($res);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Setting `error_reporting` to `-1` might not immediately "light a bulb". There's `E_ALL` for that. +1 anyways.

Comment: @Linus : Depending on your PHP version, E_ALL and -1 do not have the same behaviour.  I could not assume the PHP version here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd love to see a working example of this. The ["tip" in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) seems pretty contradictory; `E_ALL` in 4.x wouldn't cover `E_DEPRECATED` because it doesn't know about it (yet). What error messages are skipped then?

Comment: From my understanding, starting at 5.4, E_ALL is the same as -1.  Before that, E_ALL was a combination of E_ERROR, E_WARNING, etc. In 5.0.0, E_STRICT was not part of E_ALL so error_reporting(-1) would not be the same as error_reportin(E_ALL).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you output something, ending execution with a blank screen is **normal**. Try adding this to the end of your code for kicks and giggles:

```
echo('This is a test...');
```

Comment: At least it should complete the loop because I have used `header()` after this code.